# How to set different forecolor to single label?

Tags: c#

```
lblOperationType.Text = "Text";
Label l1 = new Label();
int len = lblOperationType.Text.Length - 1;
string b = Convert.ToString(lblOperationType.Text.ToCharArray()[0]);
string a = lblOperationType.Text.Substring(1, len);
l1.Text = (b);
l1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
lblOperationType.Text = l1.Text + a;
```

Is this correct code? I have to make a single label Text like 1st Letter should be red in color.

Comment: Is this Windows Forms? ASP.NET? Something else? (And your code for `b` is a very odd way of saying `string b = lblOperationType.Text.Substring(0, 1);`

Comment: @Tafari: That won't change the foreground colour for just one *letter* which is what I think the OP is after. You'd want separate text blocks within the same label, I think. (It's been a while since I've done any WPF.)

Comment: @JonSkeet yes you are right I have missed that he wants just one letter... Previous comment deleted.

Answer (score 3):

No, in general (i.e. without custom rendering yourself) a label only has a single foreground colour. Assuming this is Windows Forms, it sounds like you might want a [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) instead - that allows multiple colours, fonts etc within a single control.

As an example:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var rtb = new RichTextBox {
            Text = "Test",
            ReadOnly = true
        };
        rtb.Select(1, 3);
        rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
        rtb.DeselectAll();
        var form = new Form { Controls = { rtb } };
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

That's not terribly nice code - it would be better to set the `Rtf` property directly, with the control codes necessary to set the colour, but I'm having a tricky time getting the exact format of the RTF right.